# Retrieve firebase data where users root collection references a sibling collection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Accessing all maps works perfectly in Firebase with this path, however it grabs all maps available in the "Maps" root collection.

`let yourMapRef = Database.database().reference().child("Maps")`

I am trying to only access the maps that the user is part of. I have therefore tried to follow stack questions and firebase tutorials but i cant grasp how to do this.

For example i would like Adam to only grab his moderated maps by

`let yourMapRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(userProfile.uid)/Maps")`

How should i think around this problem and how can this be solved?

**Users** (root collection structure)

```
{
  "4g99cMTM4begwooORsO4EKNV456" : {
    "username" : "Adam",
    "Maps" : {
      "-LpYo_pQ8zIOGHHlNU1Q" : true
    }
  },
  "6g55cHXH4begwooHQvO4EKNV3xm1" : {
    "username" : "Ellen",
    "Maps" : {
      "-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp" : true
    }
  }
}
```

**Maps** (root collection structure)

```
{
  "-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp" : {
    "mapmoderators" : {
      "6g55cHXH4begwooHQvO4EKNV3xm1" : true
    },
    "mapphotoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...",
    "mapusername" : "Hello World"
  },
  "-LpYo_pQ8zIOGHHlNU1Q" : {
    "mapmoderators" : {
      "4g99cMTM4begwooORsO4EKNV456" : true
    },
    "mapphotoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/...",
    "mapusername" : "Dream"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is get the users first, then use it against the maps collection to check wether they moderate a map or not:

```
func getUsers() {
    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserID)
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

      let root = snapshot.value as? Dictionary

      if let mapsByUser = root["Maps"] as? [String: Bool] {
          for (documentId, status) in mapsByUser {
              if status {
                  // Document is true, check for the maps
                  self.getMaps(key: documentId, owner: currentUserID)
              }
          }
      }
      }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

// Check for maps
func getMaps(key:String, owner:String) {
    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("maps").child(key)
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let user = snapshot.value as? Dictionary

        if let mapsByUser = user["mapmoderators"] as? [String: Bool] {
            for (userId, status) in mapsByUser {
                if userId == owner && status == true {
                    print("Owner \(owner) manages this \(user)")
                }
            }
        }

      }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Call `getUsers()` on viewDidLoad to test this.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying to translate the answer into my project and see if it works out.

Comment: It might need an edit to meet your requirements. As I don’t see the structure/ etc in detail

Comment: Going through my code line by line. Don't know how to start a chat else i would send you my complete code.

Comment: Do you have Skype? I’m available now. Rawandahmad10@outlook.com